# Why is IP address still existing even after LAN cable was pulled out?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raspberry-pi

As in title, I tried to use Ubuntu or Kali on Raspberry pi 3. I want IP address to be immediately disappear after I pull out the cable. Is it possible? How can I config it?

Answer (score 0):

If the IP address has been assigned as a static IP address it will remain when the cable is removed. If the IP address is assigned by [DHCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol), you could change how long systems that have acquired IP addresses retain them if you can configure the [lease time](http://homenetworkadmin.com/dhcp-lease-time/) setting on the DHCP server. That setting controls how frequently a client system will try to refresh its DHCP-acquired settings. You still won't have an immediate release of the IP address, but you can reduce the amount of time the system retains the IP address. On an Ubuntu Linux system, you can [manually release a DHCP-acquired IP address with the dhclient command](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-release-ip-address-ubuntu/) `dhclient -r`, so you could enter that command when you've pulled the cable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ip utility its monitor command.

`ip monitor dev eno2 | grep -qs 'DOWN' if [ $? = 0 ];  echo "the cable is unplugged"`

otherwise maybe tools like ifplugd or netplug might be able to help

`sudo ip monitor dev eno2 | grep -qs 'DOWN' if [ $? = 0 ]; sudo ip addr flush eno2`

You could also just base it around the string in `/sys/class/net/eno2/operstate` that changes from up to down

to answer your comment:
you could flush the ip address when the interface goes down by adding your script in /etc/network/if-down.d or /etc/network/if-post-down.d depending on whether you want your script to be executed before or after the interface goes down.

As you didn't mention if it was ipv4 or ipv6
you can manipulate the ipv6 keep address or not behavior by its setting with the sysctl tool depending on your kernel version see [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/842542/why-are-ipv6-addresses-flushed-on-link-down)

`sudo sysctl net.ipv6.conf.eno2.keep_addr_on_down 
net.ipv6.conf.eno2.keep_addr_on_down = 0`

eno2 here is my second nic

Comment: Thank for answer, I want config in System to remove IP when the cable is unplugged. I don't want a script run everytime to check the cable status. I used Raspbian System, which will remove IP if the cable is pulled out. But in this System, I have a problem that I cannot fix it. So I change OS.